# Django JOIN eliminates desired columns

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to join two tables with django related to each other with a foreign key field.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField('Description', blank=True, null=True)


class Vote(models.Model):
    question        = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    profile         = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    value           = models.IntegerField('Value')
    creator         = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I tried to create a queryset by using

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(vote__creator=3).values()
```

which results in a set like this

```
+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
 ....
```

If I run a slightly similar query by hand in mysql with

```
select * from questions as t1 join votes as t2 on t1.id=question_id  where creator_id=3;
```

it results in a set like this

```
+----+-------------+------+-------------+------------+-------+------------+
| id | description | id   | question_id | profile_id | value | creator_id |
```

How can I prevent django from cutting columns from my resulting queryset? I'd really wish to retrieve a fully joined table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use objects.select_related():

```
questions = Question.objects.select_related().filter(vote__creator=3).values()
```

Comment: This unfortunately also returns a query set where the columns `id`,`question`.`description` are gathered from the DB. but not the column 'creator' for instance. I checked it with print(questions.query)

Comment: ok, so obviously the values are not extended automatically. Instead they have to be chosen manually with .values('vote__creator')
Thats not very cool, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

A `Question.objects.filter(...)` will generate the following SQL

```
select * from question where question.id in (...)`
```

So, as you can see, it's different from what you wanted (`question join votes`)

Comment: That is correct, I must have missed that out. But how can I perform a Outer join as I wish to do?